# Profile page shows overlapping on Account info section from mod account

Tags: bug, profile-page

During Winterbash, I have seen overlap in account info section of one of our mod on Movies & TV. I am not sure if its present before winterbash 2015 or not. Same appeared fine on other mod's account and mine too. Used same browser for all.

[image]

Comment: And what browser is that? (OS too)

Comment: Chrome + Ubuntu

Comment: Any extensions installed? Is this still happening? What version on Chrome?

Comment: 42.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu also showing same issue, it have cache cleaning and firebug add on. Similarly in Chromium browser for ubuntu with cache related extension and hangout and flash extension.